# The last row from the last dataframe in the list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

```
A5 <- data.frame(
                 `[A5] zuzycie` = rnorm(50, 1, 1),
                 `[A5] temp` = rnorm(50, 10, 1),
                 `[A5] level` = rnorm(50, 10, 10),
                 check.names = F
                 ) 

B5 <- data.frame(
                  `[B5] zuzycie` = rnorm(50, 1, 1),
                  `[B5] temp` = rnorm(50, 10, 1),
                  `[B5] level` = rnorm(50, 20, 10),
                  check.names = F ) 


K1 <- data.frame(
                  `[K1] zuzycie` = rnorm(50, 1, 1),
                  `[K1] temp` = rnorm(50, 10, 1),
                  `[K1] level` = rnorm(50, 20, 10),
                  check.names = F
)
co_lst <- list (A5=A5, B5=B5, K1=K1)
```

How can I read the last row from the last dataframe in the list?
Real data is more complex and dataframes are much larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_frame <- tail(co_lst,n=1)[[1]]
(last_row <- last_frame[nrow(last_frame),])
```

```
   [K1] zuzycie [K1] temp [K1] level
50     2.327333  10.19323   42.56301
```

Comment: A one-liner involving double `tail()` could be `tail(tail(co_lst, 1)[[1]], 1)`.